# get arbitrary precision when input contains floating point in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to compute central moment in Mathematica with arbitrary precision. However with different input format I got different results.

Clearly first moment should be 0 exact, but Mathematica is not giving me 0 for input with floating points. Is there any way to force it to use arbitrary precision? My input is a CSV file with floating point numbers like xxx.xx

```
CentralMoment[{3,0.7}, 1]=0.x10^-16 // very close to 0, but not exact
CentralMoment[{3,7/10}, 1]=0
//You could try the above with Wolfram alpha online
```

Comment: You can use `Chop` to replace numbers smaller than some scale (10^-15, I think) with exact zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, it does this

```
CentralMoment[{3, 0.7`16}, 1]
(*
-> 0.\[Times]10^-16
*)
```

while

```
CentralMoment[{3, 0.7}, 1]
(*
-> 0
*)
```

so presumably it's reading them as of some finite precision. Now, since

```
CentralMoment[{3, SetPrecision[0.7`12, \[Infinity]]}, 1]
(*
-> 0
*)
```

I guess what you want is `SetPrecision`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Rationalize` to convert floating point numbers to exact fractions.  `Rationalize[0.7]` will return `7/10`.  This is using exact numbers (not quite the same as *arbitrary precision*, which is usually understood as being able to use an arbitrarily large but still finite precision---as in acl's answer).